# Example for using Locust with Boto3

Tags: amazon-s3, boto3, locust

I am trying to use Locust together with Boto3 for load testing of S3, in particular for PutObject.

I found a tutorial and another github project, but both have been written for the older locustio package and seem incompatible with the current version locust 2.5.1.

https://medium.com/@allankp/populating-dashboards-with-boto3-and-locust-ff38b113349a
https://github.com/twosigma/locust-s3

I have made a short attempt at adapting this code to newer versions but this seems to require a good understanding of locust which I do not possess yet.

Does anyone have a simple beginner's example to share? Or would you rather recommend using the old locustio package or another tool altogether?

Many thanks.

Comment: Link 2 is dead..

Answer (score 2):

Helped by [this example](http://docs.locust.io/en/stable/testing-other-systems.html) in the official docs and Cyberwiz's answer, I created this bare-bones solution for my specific problem.

```python
import time
import boto3
from locust import User, task, constant, events


class BotoClient:
    def __init__(self):
        self.s3_client = boto3.client(
            's3',
            aws_access_key_id="ACCESS_KEY",
            aws_secret_access_key="SECRET_KEY"
        )

    def send(self, f, bucket_name, object_name):

        request_meta = {
            "request_type": "upload file",
            "name": "S3",
            "start_time": time.time(),
            "response_length": 0,
            "response": None,
            "context": {},
            "exception": None,
        }
        start_perf_counter = time.perf_counter()

        try:
            self.s3_client.upload_fileobj(f, bucket_name, object_name)
        except Exception as e:
            request_meta['exception'] = e

        request_meta["response_time"] = (time.perf_counter() - start_perf_counter) * 1000

        events.request.fire(**request_meta)


class BotoUser(User):
    abstract = True

    def __init__(self, env):
        super().__init__(env)
        self.client = BotoClient()

    wait_time = constant(1)


class MyUser(BotoUser):

    wait_time = constant(1)

    @task
    def send_request(self):
        with open("FILE_NAME", 'rb') as f:
            self.client.send(f, "BUCKET_NAME", "OBJECT_NAME")
```

Comment: What is the invocation command please?

Comment: For example:
locust -f your_file.py --headless --users 100 --spawn-rate 100

Answer (score 0):

The changes needed to adapt the code to version 1+ of Locust are very small.

Quoting the documentation changelog:

```
Locust class renamed to User

We’ve renamed the Locust and HttpLocust classes to User and HttpUser. The locust attribute on TaskSet instances has been renamed to user.
```